# MikroC code for sonar sensor possible bug?

Tags: mikroc

I am using three sonar sensors in my robotic project and they seem to freeze after functioning for a few seconds. I don't think it is any hardware fault. Can anyone check my code below and tell if anything is wrong?

```js
/*********************************************************************
  This is the header file for sonar sensors to check if there is any 
 object in a given range. For the pin diagram, please refer resource
 files.
 
 The main functions used here to check if there is any object are

  1. check_left()
  2. check_right()
  3. check_front()

 and they return a short value 1 if there is any object or 0 if there
 are none. So in order to use it in code, just assign the method name
 to a short variable and treat it as a boolean value 1 or 0.
*********************************************************************/

#ifndef Sonar
#define Sonar

#define HIGH    1
#define LOW     0

#define ON      1
#define OFF     0

#define INPUT   1
#define OUTPUT  0

#define Sonar1TRIG_TRIS                 TRISB.B1
#define Sonar1TRIG_LAT                  LATB.B1
#define Sonar1ECHO_TRIS                 TRISB.B0
#define Sonar1ECHO_PORT                 PORTB.B0

#define Sonar2TRIG_TRIS                 TRISB.B3
#define Sonar2TRIG_LAT                  LATB.B3
#define Sonar2ECHO_TRIS                 TRISB.B2
#define Sonar2ECHO_PORT                 PORTB.B2

#define Sonar3TRIG_TRIS                 TRISB.B5
#define Sonar3TRIG_LAT                  LATB.B5
#define Sonar3ECHO_TRIS                 TRISB.B4
#define Sonar3ECHO_PORT                 PORTB.B4

#define CM40                            1250
#define CM10                            1125

/********************* Initiating variables *************************/

short right_flag, left_flag, front_flag, i, j, k;

/***************** Initiate Sonar PORTC and PORTD *******************/
void init_sonar() {

    // Sonar One
    Sonar1ECHO_TRIS = INPUT;
    // Sonar Two
    Sonar2ECHO_TRIS = INPUT;
    // Sonar Three
    Sonar3ECHO_TRIS = INPUT;

    // Sonar Trigger 1
    Sonar1TRIG_TRIS = OUTPUT;
    // Sonar Trigger 2
    Sonar2TRIG_TRIS = OUTPUT;
    // Sonar Trigger 3
    Sonar3TRIG_TRIS = OUTPUT;
}

/*************** Generate a pulse to start sonar 1 ******************/
void Trigger_1() {

    //TRIGGER HIGH
    Sonar1TRIG_LAT = HIGH;
    // Delay
    Delay_us(15);
    //TRIGGER LOW
    Sonar1TRIG_LAT = LOW;
}

/*************** Generate a pulse to start sonar 2 ******************/
void Trigger_2() {

    //TRIGGER HIGH
    Sonar2TRIG_LAT = HIGH;
    // Delay
    Delay_us(15);
    //TRIGGER LOW
    Sonar2TRIG_LAT = LOW;
}

/*************** Generate a pulse to start sonar 3 ******************/
void Trigger_3() {

    //TRIGGER HIGH
    Sonar3TRIG_LAT = HIGH;
    // Delay
    Delay_us(15);
    //TRIGGER LOW
    Sonar3TRIG_LAT = LOW;
}

/******************* Check left using Sonar *************************/
short check_left() {

    // Initiate Timer and variables
    T1CON = 0b00010000;
    left_flag = 0; i = 0;

    while(i < 5) {

        Delay_ms(1);
        // Send a pulse
        Trigger_2();

        //Wait till ECHO sets it value to High
        while (Sonar2ECHO_PORT == 0) {asm nop;}

        // Now start the timer and wait for the falling edge
        T1CON.TMR1ON = 0;
        TMR1H = 0x00; TMR1L = 0x00;
        T1CON.TMR1ON = 1;

        while((TMR1H << 8 | TMR1L) < CM40) {
            if(Sonar2ECHO_PORT == 1) {continue;}
            else {
                // There is something inside this range
                left_flag++;
                break;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    
    if (left_flag > 2) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

/********************* Check right using Sonar **********************/
short check_right() {

    // Initiate Timer and variables
    T1CON = 0b00010000;
    right_flag = 0; j = 0;

    while(j < 5) {

        Delay_ms(1);
        // Send a pulse
        Trigger_1();

        //Wait till ECHO sets it value to High
        while (Sonar1ECHO_PORT == 0) {asm nop;}

        // Now start the timer and wait for the falling edge
        T1CON.TMR1ON = 0;
        TMR1H = 0x00; TMR1L = 0x00;
        T1CON.TMR1ON = 1;

        while((TMR1H << 8 | TMR1L) < CM40) {
            if(Sonar1ECHO_PORT == 1) {continue;}
            else {
                // There is something inside this range
                right_flag++;
                break;
            }
        }
        j++;
    }

    if (right_flag > 2) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

/********************** Check front using Sonar *********************/
short check_front() {

    // Initiate Timer and variables
    T1CON = 0b00010000;
    front_flag = 0; k = 0;

    while(k < 5) {

        Delay_ms(1);
        // Send a pulse
        Trigger_3();

        //Wait till ECHO sets it value to High
        while (Sonar3ECHO_PORT == 0) {asm nop;}

        // Now start the timer and wait for the falling edge
        T1CON.TMR1ON = 0;
        TMR1H = 0x00; TMR1L = 0x00;
        T1CON.TMR1ON = 1;

        while((TMR1H << 8 | TMR1L) < CM10) {
            if(Sonar3ECHO_PORT == 1) {continue;}
            else {
                // There is something inside this range
                front_flag++;
                break;
            }
        }
        k++;
    }

    if (front_flag > 2) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
#endif
```

```js
#include "Sonar.h"
#include "LED.h"
#include "IR.h"
#include "Motor.h"

#define ON      1
#define OFF     0

// Initiate
void init_main(void);

char inter_value, return_value;
short Ll, Rr, Ff;

/****************************** Initializing Codes ****************************/
// Initiate main panels
void init_main() {
    init_sensor();
    init_motor();
    init_sonar();
    init_PWM();
    init_led();
}

/************************************** MAIN **********************************/
void main() {

    // Initiate panels
    init_main();
    

    while(ON) {
      
      Rr = check_right();
      Ff = check_front();
      Ll = check_left(); 

      if (Ff == 1) {
        LED6 = ON;
        LED7 = OFF;
        }
        else {
        LED7 = ON;
        LED6 = OFF;
      }
      if (Ll == 1) {
        LED1 = ON;
        LED2 = OFF;
        }
        else {
        LED2 = ON;
        LED1 = OFF;
      }
      if (Rr == 1) {
        LED3 = ON;
        LED4 = OFF;
        }
        else {
        LED4 = ON;
        LED3 = OFF;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no `main` or `_start` or `setup` function in your code. Where does the execution start?